# View data from DataBase in React JS file

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I want to count the number of teachers and students from database and view the count in a table in React JS, but i can't view the count in the table.

In my database if the TypeID = 1 it is teacher, and if TypeID = 2 it is a student

This is the ReportsTable.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import ReportsData from './ReportsData.json';
import '../Table.css'
import Axios from 'axios';


export const ReportsTable = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    Axios
      .get("http://localhost:3003/reports")
      .then(result => setData(result.data));
    console.log(data);
    debugger;
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table" >
        <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">الاسم</th>
            <th scope="col">العدد</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(item => {
            return <tr> عدد المعلمين
              <td>{item.id }</td>
            </tr>
          })}
          {data.map(item => {
            return <tr> عدد الطلاب
              <td>{item.id }</td>
            </tr>
          })}
          
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  )
}
export default ReportsTable;
```

And this is the index.js file in server folder

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "finaldatabase"
});

app.get("/reports", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT COUNT(SSN) FROM usertype WHERE TypeID=1", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(result)
    }
  })
});

app.listen(3003, () => {
  console.log("running on port 3003");
})
```